# Where can I find the Android Studio templates for Activity and gradle script?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-appcompat

I am using the [new appCompat v22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), and I would like to change the templates used by Android Studio.

Currently, the Android Studio templates create Activities that extend `ActionBarActivity` which has been deprecated in v22.1. I would like to switch to `AppCompatActivity` without changing the code each time.

Is it possible to change them without waiting for the next Android Studio update?

Comment: Didn't know ActionBarActivity was deprecated... Oh, Android, Android...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can be done:

Activity templates are located here: ***[ANDROID_STUDIO_DIR]\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities***

1. find the template you want to change
2. open ***\XXXActivity\root\src\app_package\XXXActivity.java.ftl***, find and replace import of *ActionBarActivity* and *ActionBarActivity* with *AppCompatActivity*.